# Want to run a command after another dependency is installed

Tags: shell

i have a shell script which is trying to start a docker container.however docker is only getting installed as part of a different script which is executed after mine. Is there a way i can have my command wait in the background - say like 10 mnts or 15 mnts and then run.

Comment: Is it possible to rearrange the order of execution?

Comment: `sleep 600` does what you're asking but this sounds like a really convoluted way to solve this problem. See also [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).